# Volley Request Body not being execulted

Tags: android, response, android-volley

I have the following method in Volley.When i call the method only one Log info gets printed in log.

```
 private void loadFromCloudAPI() {
            Log.i("apiresponse","inside api call");
            queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getQueue();
            CacheRequest attendanceDetailsCache  = new CacheRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                    final String jsonString;
                    Log.i("apiresponse","inside api call");
                    try {

                        jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                        Log.i("apiresponse",jsonString);
                        JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(jsonString);
                        renderDataInTheAttendanceDetailsLayout(jsonArray);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException|JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("apiresponse",e+"");

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                   Map<String ,String > data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("authenticate","false");
                    data.put("class_id","1");
                    data.put("section_id","4");
                    data.put("student_id","1");

                    return super.getParams();
                }
            };

            attendanceDetailsCache.setTag(this);
            queue.add(attendanceDetailsCache);


        }
```

Output::

```
apiresponse: inside api call
```

Only one info Log ? How ? I cannot log the response nor the error , when i try the same thing using ARC in browser i get the response. What might be the issue ?

Comment: You should add a log to `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` to make sure an error doesn't occur while executing the request.

Comment: Thank you George , i hadnt noticed that i didnt put log inside volleyError blog i thought i did but i was confused with that UnsupportedEncodingException ... i  found my error :)